# Select the specific column of ListView and print it in a new messagebox in C#.net

Tags: c#, .net, windows, listview, programming-languages

I've just started to use ListView in C#.net.

I got to know how to add items and subitems. Going through the listview I wanted to fetch all the data from a whole column with multiple rows.

I want to know how to do this.

I found this code to list a specific selected data from a row:

ListView.SelectedIndexCollection sel = listView1.SelectedIndices;

```
        if (sel.Count == 1)
        {
            ListViewItem selItem = listView1.Items[sel[0]];
            MessageBox.Show(selItem.SubItems[2].Text);
        }
```

That was helpful but i want to list all the items in a row, may be i want to add all the column items in array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    private string[] GetListViewItemColumns(ListViewItem item) {
        var columns = new string[item.SubItems.Count];
        for (int column = 0; column < columns.Length; column++) {
            columns[column] = item.SubItems[column].Text;
        }
        return columns;
    }
```

I would recommend some caution against doing this.  A ListView is really meant to *display* information, it is not a great collection class.  Getting the data out of it is slow and crummy, it can only store strings.  Keep the data in your program in its original form, maybe a `List<Foo>`.  Now it is simple and fast.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items) {
    // Do something with item
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do this by 

`foreach(ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
{
  foreach(var subtem in item.SubItems)
{
   // Do what ever you want to do with the items.
}
}`

Comment: I didn't get it actually.  how to fetch out the string or integer from the column in this loop?